# How to add jpg images information as a column in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, image-preprocessing

I have jpg images stored in a folder. For ex: 11_lion_king.jpg,22_avengers.jpg etc.

I have a data frame as below:

```
data_movie.head()

movie_id  genre 
11       ['action','comedy]
22       ['animation',comedy]
..........
```

I want to add a new column `movie_image` into the `data_movie` data frame with the jpg information mapped correctly with `movie_id` column as shown below:

```
movie_id  genre                movie_image
11       ['action','comedy]    11_lion_king.jpg
22       ['animation',comedy]  22_avengers.jpg
.........
```

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you a list of the filenames called `movie_images`

```
# Could get filenames with:
# import os;  movie_images = os.listdir("./folder/with/images/")
movie_filenames = ["11_lion_king.jpg", "22_avengers.jpg"]
```

First create a mapping between the ID values and the filenames:

```
# Use the "_" to split the filename and take the first items, the ID
mapping = {f.split("_")[0]: f for f in movie_filenames}    # <-- a dictionary-comprehension
```

Now add a column of some empty values (whatever you like) that will hold the `movie_image` values:

```
data_movie["movie_image"] = pd.Series()    # will be filled with NaN values until populated
```

Now iterate over this mapping, inserting the movie filenames for the correct movie IDs:

```
for movie_id, movie_image_filename in mapping.items():
    df.loc[df.movie_id == movie_id, "movie_image"] = movie_image_filename
```

This should produce the output dataframe you described.

As a side note (in case you are ever tempted): never load the actual images into a  pandas dataframe. It is best to load them as NumPy arrays or something similar. Pandas DataFrames are in essence just annotated NumPy arrays anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Slight addendum to the above solution:

```
##First create a mapping between the ID values and the filenames:

# Use the "_" to split the filename and take the first items, the ID
mapping = {f.split("_")[0]: f for f in movie_filenames}     # <-- a dictionary-comprehension

##Now iterate over this mapping, inserting the movie filenames for the correct movie IDs:

for movie_id, movie_image_filename in mapping.items():
    data_movie.loc[data_movie.movie_id.astype(str) == movie_id, "movie_image"] = movie_filenames
```

Aliter way using`map` function:

```
mapping = {f.split("_")[0]: f for f in movie_filenames}

data_movie["movie_image"] = data_movie['movie_id'].astype(str).map(mapping)
```